# When saving a file, TypeError for my write argument must be in string

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, save

I am trying to save an array of data using numpy (np) but I keep getting this error:  `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`. I am confused on how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
# Read and pre-process input images
    images = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 3, 512, 512))
    for i in range(n):
        image = img
        image.setflags(write=1)
        # Change data layout from HWC to CHW
        image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))  
        images[i] = image
        
        # image is read and convert to fp16 in range 0->1
        eoim = image
        eoim16 = eoim.astype(np.float16)
       
       
        preprocessed_image_path = 'C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Ubotica/IOD/cloud_detect/'
        formated_image_file = "output_patch_fp"
        f = open(preprocessed_image_path + "/" + formated_image_file + ".txt", "w")
        
        np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
        np.save(f, eoim16)
        f.close()
        
        # divide by 255 to get value in range 0->1 if necessary (depends on input pixel format)
        if(eoim16.max()>1.0):
            eoim16 = np.divide(eoim16,255)
          
    return eoim16
```

I tried saving it as a string also with set_printoptions, but that does not work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you're adding an extra `/` when you're opening your file, also try using `mode='wb'` or just `np.save(filename, object_data)`

Comment: `printoptions` has nothing to do with `np.save`.  It isn't writing text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to write bytes to the file, but the mode you use is 'w', which writes by default text. All you need is to change 'w' when opening the file to 'wb'(from write bytes) and it should fix it.

Cheers!